# Introducing bias via combining probability outputs from multiple models

Tags: probability, classification, survival, svm, boosting

I am working on a classification task, where I am trying to estimate the probability that a patient may not die.

I did use a Survival Analysis approach at first, but the results seemed unintuitive and the features did not seem to be well suited for this task.

What I now do instead is that for each time period, I build a classification model that predicts the output probability of whether a person dies in time, t. I then combine these probabilities in the following way for each patient, i and time point, t -

q[i,t] = (1-p[i,1])×(1-p[i,2])...(1-p[i,t-1])×p[i,t]. Here, q is the probability that patient - i survives until time t.

Assuming that the patient dies in the middle of the year (this comes from the way we collect patient data), I then calculate the expected time of patient survival as follows -

Time to survive = (0.5 × q[i,1]) + (1.5 × q[i,2]) + (2.5 × q[i, 3]) +...+ (0.5 × t × q[i, t]).

When I compare this time to survive, regardless of what classification model I use I overestimate the time to survive by a factor of 1.5 - 2.5 times the actual time to survive. I have been trying to think of different ways in which I might be introducing bias in my calculations.